# Magento: how do not show new product in the home page

Tags: magento-1.8, product, sales

I don't want show the "New Product" section in the home page.
In effect, at the moment, i've no new product configured in the backend but, anyway, the strings "New Products" and "Sale Products" (i want also it to remove) are in the home page.

How can i remove them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the homepage is a cms page. Go to Cms->Pages edit the homepage and check in the content or layout update xml fields for something related to new products.
Remove what you find and save the page.

Answer (score 1):

Goto admin>CMS>page> select your home page and then goto it  design tab

There check  is exiting or not

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
    <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type>
        <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
        <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
    </action>
</block>
</reference>
```

[image]

Also, New Product Collection `depends on  product attributes news_from_date & news_from_date.`

Answer (score 0):

go to `/magento root/app/design/frontend/theme name/template/catalog/product/`

there is file `homepage.phtml` comment the following section

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home_category_images')->toHtml(); ?> 
<!--<div class="new-products">
<div class="new-products-inner">
<div class="new"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_new')->setTemplate('catalog/product/new.phtml')->toHtml(); ?></div>
<div class="sellers"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mageshop/popular')->setTemplate('catalog/product/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?></div>
</div>
</div>-->
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home_sitepolicy_block')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Magento SE unfortunately there is no such page `homepage.phtml` in magento may be you have created that for your purpose please be more specific when answering.